# Identifying the programming language the following code is written in

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, pseudocode

I just started learning computer programming and I want to learn more about programming algorithm. I have bought some reference books. However, when I read the book, I found some codes like this:

```
function Get-Number(n)
    Q ← NIL
    Enqueue(Q,1)
    While n > 0 do
        x ← Dequeue(Q)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,2x)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,3x)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,5x)
        n ← n – 1
    return x

function Unique-Enqueue(Q,x)
    i ← 0
    while i < |Q| ^ Q[i] < x do
        i ← i + 1
    if i < |Q| ^ x = Q[i] then
        return
    Insert(Q,i,x)
```

I have learnt some basics of C language but I did not see that kind of code and I cannot understand the algorithm. Do anyone know what kind of programming language is for the above codes? Thank you so much!

Comment: While there are languages that have such symbols like left-arrows and such, it might just be *pseudo-code*, do describe an algorithm in a code-like language. Without knowing the book or the context where you found the code you show, there's really nothing more anyone can say.

Comment: The *book itself* very likely describes the notation used in its very first chapters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). It looks like the meaning of the syntax is as follows:

- `function F(x)` declares a new **function** F with some **argument(s)**
- `Q <- value` **assigns** value to the variable called Q, creating Q if it does not already exist
- `someFunction(x)` **calls** `someFunction`, passing in the argument `x`
- `while` is a **[while loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)**
- `if`...`then` is an **if statement**, the same as in C but with a more English-like syntax
- `return x` exits the current function and returns x as its **return value**, or no return value if no return value is specified (void function in C terminology)
- `|Q|` yields the size of the collection Q
- `<` means the same as in C and in mathematics (less than operator)
- `Q[i]` yields the element in collection Q at position i
- `^` probably means logical AND, because that is what it means in mathematics

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Calling `Get-number(n)` returns n<sup>th</sup> smallest natural number that has only 2, 3, or 5 as prime factors. The list of such numbers looks like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, ...}
```

### Detailed Explanation

The complete code has two functions. I'll explain each step one-by-one.

#### Get-number(n)

```
function Get-Number(n)
    Q ← NIL
    Enqueue(Q,1)
    While n > 0 do
        x ← Dequeue(Q)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,2x)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,3x)
        Unique-Enqueue(Q,5x)
        n ← n – 1
    return x
```

- An empty queue named `Q` is created. In the next step, we push 1 to it, making `Q = [1]`.
- We take out the rightmost number `x`. Then call `Unique-Enqueue(Q,2x)`, `Unique-Enqueue(Q,3x)`, and `Unique-Enqueue(Q,5x)` respectively.
- At the end, we return the final value of `x`. So effectively, we discard the queue `Q` at the end of the function and retain the final value of `x` only.

Overall, given an input `n`, this function will return an output `x` which can be obtained after doing all the function calls as mentioned above.
Now let's look at the other function.

#### Unique-Enqueue(Q,x)

```
function Unique-Enqueue(Q,x)
    i ← 0
    while i < |Q| ^ Q[i] < x do
        i ← i + 1
    if i < |Q| ^ x = Q[i] then
        return
    Insert(Q,i,x)
```

- In the current `Q`, keep moving to the right until you hit a number 
  not satisfying`Q[i] < x` i.e., find the first number in the queue moving from left to right which is at least as big as `x`.
- There are three possible scenarios. If this number is equal to `x`, stop. If this number is greater than `x`, insert `x` before this number.  If there is no such number, insert `x`at the end.

### Sample case

Let's say we call `Get-number(4)`:

- Initially `Q = [1]`.
- `Q = [2,3,5]` after first loop.
- `Q = [3,4,5,6,10]` after second loop.
- `Q = [4,5,6,9,10,15]` after third loop.
- `Q = [5,6,8,9,10,12,15,20]` after fourth loop.

Hence `Get-number(4)` returns `4` since that was the last value for our `x`.